# Lubuntu audacious configuration problem

Tags: lubuntu, audacious

I believe this is a bug in lubuntu 14.04.2 (Trusty), a configuration control issue.

In the lubuntu desktop amd64 iso, audacious is installed via the disk image in casper.  The package revision is indicated as:

```
Package: audacious
Architecture: amd64
Version: 3.4.3-1
```

But if you try to install audacious from the repository with the same version number, you will get dependancy errors in libvorbis0a.  The casper image does not install libvorbis (ogg), but the apt-get install will try.  It will fail because there are two versions of the same package kicking around.  One is a dependancy for one thing (forgot what specifically) and the other for pavucontrol/audacious.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy audacious libvorbis0a`

Comment: Not sure how relevant that would be.  I found this by trying to create a local repository of installed packages and then installing from the local repository.  If I install from the local repository, I had apt-get install audacious and pavucontrol both producing errors which I was eventually able to trace back to this problem.  But if I installed from the internet repositories I didn't get the error because it didn't try to install the packages, saying they were already installed.  For whatever it's worth, here's the output requested:

Comment: Had to do this in two passes because I ran out of characters:
audacious:
  Installed: 3.4.3-1
  Candidate: 3.4.3-1
  Version table:
 *** 3.4.3-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
apt-cache policy libvorbis0a
libvorbis0a:
  Installed: 1.3.2-1.3ubuntu1
  Candidate: 1.3.2-1.3ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 1.3.2-1.3ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
This is for the internet install.  Local repository install failed.